# How to change data on select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, json

need a small help to change data from option selected.

The data is populated first to the dropdown option list from a JSON result, in the same JSON is the second data thta need to be changed on select the option from dropdown.

What i want os to change the price on select the store.

This is my javascript code:

```
    $(function() {
    var pricestore = [{"product_id":"1","store_id":"1","price":"120.00","sequence":"0","id":"1","parent_id":"0","name":"Store 1","email":"store1@store1.com"},{"product_id":"1","store_id":"2","price":"140.00","sequence":"0","id":"2","parent_id":"0","name":"Store 2","email":"store2@store2.com"}];
    $.each(pricestore, function(i, option) {
        $('#sel').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.id).text(option.name));    
    }),
    //Trying to populate the price on div id
    $$('#price-store').each(function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = pricestore;
        });
})
```

This is the HTML to get the data

```
<select id="sel"></select>
<div id="price-store"></div>
```

Here is also an example on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/A386B

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqetf/)

As per what i understood from your question you need to show the price in the div as the dropdown values are changed. You can use below method. You need to use use a change event on the `dropdown`.

This approach uses [Index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the option element selected and retrieves the corresponding record from `JSON`.

```
 $('#sel').change(function () {
        $('#price-store').text(
                pricestore[$('option:selected', this).index()].price);
    });
```

Another way is to use `data-attributes` on the option element to store the respective price and retrieve it on change of dropdown value.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vNz5E/)

```
 $('#sel').append($('<option>',
                       {
                           "value" :option.id,
                           "data-price" :option.price
                       }).text(option.name));
}),
$('#sel').change(function () {
    $('#price-store').text($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks PSL, this what i want :).

Comment: Quick question, how can i do to keep all time the lower value from price ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dario Sorry i couldn't understand your question clearly. COuld you provide with example...

Comment: For example, if i have Price: 50, 20, 30 - Store: 1, 2, 3, the first selected will be 50, the question is if can be all time the lower value first, in this case 20. Thanks

Comment: SO basically you want to sort your json based on lowest price right?

Answer (score 0):

You use `$$` to select your div instead of `$`. `$('#price-store')`
The second parameter of the function passed to the `.each()` method is the element not the first. `function(i, el) {`
Why are you using `.each()` for one div?
You'll have to format the data in `pricestore` to display it in a div, otherwise all you'll get is `[Object object],[Object object]`.

Answer (score 0):

Or this one:

```
<div id="price-store"></div
<form>
    <select id="price">
        <option>120</option>
        <option>140</option>
        <option>160</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and:

```
$('#price').change(function() {
 $('#price-store').text($('#price').find(":selected").text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XcSZL/8/